# wicked_pdf / wkhtml - support for css tables using tr.odd and tr.even to change background colour

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Does the wicked_pdf gem/plugin and the underlying wkhtmltopdf provide support for striping of alternating columns using css of tbody, tr.even and the corresponding tr.odd?

I have this in my css file (in the public folder) but its not rendering the colours properly.

```
table {
width: 90%;
border: 1px solid #999999;
}

th, td {
    padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    font-size: 90%;
/*  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
*/  text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}

tbody, tr.even {
    background-color: green;
}

tbody, tr.odd {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Currently I get only yellow across all the cells.

[image: Alternating colours in css not rendering]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
tr.even {
    background-color: green;
}

tr.odd {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Actually this was my error. I had styled dynamically with jquery on the html page, but need to call javascript with wicked_pdf. Hopefully I can get that to work. The jquery creates the class of even and the table with wicked_pdf is not implementing them. My error. Was just going form the example in a book and missed re-reading the html definition. Tired I guess and learning so much at present sometimes one misses the simple things. Guess my next question will be on Javascript with wicked_pdf