# wicked_pdf - jquery css zeba style table body only (Rails 3.2.3) and where to place css/javascript files (public or app/assets)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

This links to my previous question which was about styling a table with css. What I didn't add and realise now that this was an error is that when rendering the page as html some jquery is utilised.

[wicked_pdf / wkhtml - support for css tables using tr.odd and tr.even to change background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839778/wicked-pdf-wkhtml-support-for-css-tables-using-tr-odd-and-tr-even-to-change)

The jquery for this is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tbody tr:even').addClass('stripe');
  $('tbody tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('stripeHover');
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('stripeHover');
  });
});
```

I assume that as we are rendering a PDF file that the hover is redundant so this could be reduced to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tbody tr:even').addClass('stripe');
});
```

Here is the wicked_pdf_helper.rb file I am using. With the asset pipeline I'm not sure if I am meant to be creating my files in public, or in app/assets/javascripts. From my limitd understanding and looking on here to answer my questions + reviewing changes to the gem it seems that the changes from Rails 2 -> 3 -> 3.1 -> 3.2 have all impacted this.

Heres the latest helper file file I have used:

```
module WickedPdfHelper
  def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
    css_dir = Rails.root.join('public','stylesheets')
    sources.collect { |source|
      "<style type='text/css'>#{File.read(css_dir.join(source+'.css'))}</style>"
}.join("\n").html_safe
  end

  def pdf_image_tag(img, options={})
    image_tag "file:///#{Rails.root.join('public', 'images', img)}", options
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(jsfile, options={})
    #javascript_src_tag "file:///#{Rails.root.join('public','javascripts',jsfile)}", options
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
    sources.collect{ |source| wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(source, {}) }.join("\n").html_safe
  end

  module Assets
    def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
      sources.collect { |source|
        "<style type='text/css'>#{read_asset(source+".css")}</style>"
  }.join("\n").html_safe
    end

    def wicked_pdf_image_tag(img, options={})
      image_tag "file://#{asset_pathname(img).to_s}", options
    end

    def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(jsfile, options={})
      javascript_include_tag "file://#{asset_pathname(jsfile).to_s}", options
    end

    def wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
      sources.collect { |source|
        "<script type='text/javascript'>#{read_asset(source+".js")}</script>"
  }.join("\n").html_safe
    end

    private

    def asset_pathname(source)
      if Rails.configuration.assets.compile == false
        File.join(Rails.public_path, asset_path(source))
      else
        Rails.application.assets.find_asset(source).pathname
      end
    end

    def read_asset(source)
      if Rails.configuration.assets.compile == false
        IO.read(asset_pathname(source))
      else
        Rails.application.assets.find_asset(source).to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The previous version of the file was:

```
module WickedPdfHelper
  def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
    options = sources.extract_options!
    if request.try(:format).to_s == 'application/pdf'
      #css_dir = Rails.root.join('public','stylesheets')
      css_dir = Rails.root.join('app','assets', 'stylesheets')
      refer_only = options.delete(:refer_only)
      sources.collect { |source|
        source.sub!(/\.css$/o,'')
        if refer_only
          stylesheet_link_tag "file://#{Rails.root.join('public','stylesheets',source+'.css')}", options
        else
          "<style type='text/css'>#{File.read(css_dir.join(source+'.css'))}</style>"
        end
      }.join("\n").html_safe
    else
      sources.collect { |source|
        stylesheet_link_tag(source, options)
      }.join("\n").html_safe
    end
  end

  # def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
  #   sources.collect { |source|
  #     "<style type='text/css'>#{Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{source}.css")}</style>"
  #   }.join("\n").gsub(/url\(['"](.+)['"]\)(.+)/,%[url("#{wicked_pdf_image_location("\\1")}")\\2]).html_safe
  # end

  def pdf_image_tag(img, options={})
    if request.try(:format).to_s == 'application/pdf'
      image_tag "file://#{Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', img)}", options rescue nil
    else
      image_tag img.to_s, options rescue nil
    end
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(jsfile, options={})
    if request.try(:format).to_s == 'application/pdf'
      jsfile.sub!(/\.js$/o,'')
      javascript_src_tag "file://#{Rails.root.join('public','javascripts',jsfile + '.js')}", options
    else
      javascript_src_tag jsfile, options
    end
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
    options = sources.extract_options!
    sources.collect{ |source| wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(source, options) }.join("\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

The template (genie_help_base.pdf.erb) file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%#= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :refer_only => true %>
    <%#= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application", :refer_only => true %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "static_pages/genie_v23_help" %>    
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<!--     <%#= render 'layouts/shim' %>  -->   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The layout template for html (genie_v23_help_base.html.erb) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'static_pages/genie_v23_help/shared/help_header.html.erb' %>       
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'static_pages/genie_v23_help/shared/help_footer' %>
      <h4><strong>Did this show up in only the html on screen</strong></h4>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css file

```
table {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

th, td {
  padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
  font-size: 90%;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;    
}

/*tr.even {
    background-color: #efefef;
}*/


.stripe { 
  background-color: #dddddd;
  /*color: #666666;*/
}

tr.stripeHover {
  background-color: #FFFACD;
}

tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #FFFACD;
}
```

Finally the show method in my controller where this is all called from:

```
  def static_page
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
        render :template => show_page,
               :layout => 'genie_v23_help_base'
    end
    format.pdf do
        render :pdf => show_page,
               :layout => 'genie_v23_help_base.pdf.erb',
               :template => "#{show_page}.html.erb",
               :handlers => :erb,
               :disable_external_links => true,
               :disable_javascript => false,
               :show_as_html => params[:debug],
               :print_media_type => true
      end
    end
  end
```

So I at present cannot get the jquery striping function to work.

I want to get this working and if successful will most likely build a sample type app to put up on GitHub as there doesn't seem to be an up-to-date version with Rails 3.2.3 using the stylesheets and jquery to demonstrate this.

Do I need to use an include statement in a file somewhere? If so where 'application'?

With the update to the helper (tobiashm 18 days ago Use precompiled assets if needed) how does one specify whether its the 'regular' methods or the methods in the Asset module?
If I don't comment out the following I get an error.

```
def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(jsfile, options={})
  #javascript_src_tag "file:///#{Rails.root.join('public','javascripts',jsfile)}", options
end
```

Changed the javascript_src_tag to javascript_include_tag so compliant with Rails 3.2+

```
def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(jsfile, options={})
  javascript_include_tag "file:///#{Rails.root.join('public','javascripts',jsfile)}", options
end
```

Does anyone have a hosted sample app /app demonstrating all of this?

Summary - trying to get css zebra striping in a PDF using jquery to set the class name in the html rendered file, so the css styling can be applied.

Thanks in advance, Mark

Comment: The javascripts are usually in `app/assets/javascripts`. Is that where you are placing them? Also I believe you said that the JQuery works when rendering html. Perhaps the javascript files are not included in the template that is rendered to PDF?

Comment: Javascripts in both public/javascripts (only the zebra_stripe_tables.js NOT jquery/jquery_ujs), and its also in 'app/assets/javascripts'. I think the js files are not included in the template which is why its not rendering. And this is somehow related to the wicked_pdf helpers. Just cannot figure out how (Yet!). Thanks for your time on the Rails Helpline.

Answer (score 0):

Your pdf layout is using just regular

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

When you should be using

```
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```